# IIS 7 application automatically redirecting

Tags: iis-7

I have 2 servers, server A and server B. Both have IIS7 and same OS. I published through my VS2008 the same website on both servers. the problem is on one the application in IIS7 website works on the other it doesnt. 
Server A - IIS7 - WebsiteA - Application (Works)
Server B - IIS7 - WebsiteA - Application (Does not work)

what are the things that i could be missing to configure IIS7 in server B ?

Comment: So many things.  Can you tell us what problems you are getting?

Comment: Wow, how can we help you with "this" much info? Look into the errors and please be more specific about the environments (both servers and your app settings).

Comment: sorry sorry. Ok so the environments on both servers are exactly the same. i created 1 website on each of the servers IIS. the published my code in them. same code for both sites. made an application of one folder on both sites. then ran both sites, where application opens in one and not in other.

Comment: now the problem happening in the server B site is thatwhen i click on the application in IE, the IP address i see on the status bar is completely different than the one that should be seen (the servers own).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what machine the IP Address is referring to.

It's possible you have firewall's, routers, and host configuration files which are effecting this.

Run a tracert to your server, and to the ip address and see where your route is going wrong.
Check you don't have multiple IP Addresses assigned to the same machine.

If you can, ask a member of your network team to help you out.
To help you more, we need to know the details of your infrastructure.